# Smartsheet API Add User with Defined Locale

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1

We have started to use Smartsheet for our data capture processes.

Most users are set as unlicensed users that have access to sheets developed in-house to capture any required data. As we have 1000's of users, we need to be able to manage this user pool.

So I have some C# code that will pull our current user list and loop through using the Smartsheet API to add them.

This is accomplished by using the AddUser API call that has a User object as a parameter.

All of this works, but the issue is the object User does not have a locale property.

After creating the user, I can pull the record back, by calling the GetUser API call which returns a UserProfile object which does have a Locale property that I can set.

There is only API call that saves these changes which is the UpdateUser method that only accepts the User object, which does not have a locale property.

Is it possible to set the locale for a user and save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to set user `locale` via the Smartsheet API. The docs don't describe any way to set that property, and if I try to include it in an **Add User** or **Update User** request, I receive an error response in return. I even checked the "API & Developers" category within the [Smartsheet Community Forum](https://search.smartsheet.com/community/#q=%22locale%22&t=CommunitySiteResults&sort=relevancy&numberOfResults=25&f:@communitycategory=%5BAPI%20%26%20Developers%5D), but it seems like nobody's raised this question there before.

A couple of suggestions for you:

1- Create a new post in the "API & Developers" category of the [Smartsheet Community Forum](https://community.smartsheet.com/categories/api-developers). (Note: You'll need to sign in before you can do so.) Although Stack Overflow should always be your #1 go-to place for API-related questions/answers, this Smartsheet forum is a secondary venue where your question may reach different/additional people.

2- [Contact Smartsheet Support](https://help.smartsheet.com/contact/smartsheetapp) to ask them directly if it's possible to set user `locale` via the API. Although the Smartsheet support folks sometimes chime in on Stack Overflow and/or Smartsheet Community posts, contacting them directly is the surest way to get a response.